# How to display only the second column and than compare with second text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

i want to only display the second column ,

this is my code

```
with open('try.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1:] for line in file1 if line.strip())
print file1_data
```

I only want to display the second column , but its also diplaying 3rd with it

This is the text file

```
E5 BAT One 
E5 BALL Two 
E5 CRICKET Three
```

Than i have to find the `Bat` which is in second column of textfile1 in `second` text file

```
    ?Bat03|Batsman
    This is the goods of cricket
    ?Balt|Bowler
    Both can be use by batsman and bowler
    ?Bat133|Swimmer
    Swiming is the best exercise
```

So the `Bat` which is in second column of `textfile1` we goto second text file and find Bat and ignore value after `|` , if `Bat` in second text file before `|` found than display it

```
with open('second.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        if line[:1] == '?':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                output.writerow(row + [file1_data])
        else:
            outputfile.write(line)
```

`Required output`

```
?Bat03|Batsman
        This is the goods of cricket
?Bat133|Swimmer
        Swiming is the best exercise
```

Comment: You mean column, right?

Comment: @mgilson I further explain it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just index the line after splitting?

```
line.split()[1]
```

instead of:

```
line.split(None,2)[1:]
```

Of course, this won't be happy with the dictionary either.  I'm not sure why you have a dict in there.  If it's all the same to you, I'd advise that you use a `list` instead.

```
file1_data = [line.split()[1] for line in file1 if line.strip()]
```

If you actually want to keep the dictionary, then you've already almost got what you want.  The first column can be constructed from `file1_data.keys()` which returns an iterable (on python2.x it is a list, on python3.x it is a set-like object).  Of course, since this is a dictionary, all order from the original file is lost.

Comment: I have to work with keys in my further code , thats y i use dictionary

Comment: @Angel -- if that's the case, you need to be more explicit about what you want to have as the key and what you want to have as the value.  In your code, the second column is accessible via `file1_data.keys()` and the rest of the line is `file1_data.values()`.